# Rails Rendering Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever I'm trying to render the games partial, the view it's being rendered in gives a nil return.

here is the games partial:

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
     <tr> 
     <% @games.each do |game| %>
       <td><%= game.name %></td> 

       <td><%= link_to('Pick!', vote_up_game_path(game.id), :method => :post) %></td> 
     </tr> 
       <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `@games` as a local variable to the partial.  Consider looking at the documentation on its usage.  I also feel the flash-notice should not belong inside the partial.  You might also want to correct your code

```
<% games.each do |game| %>
  <tr> 
    <td><%= game.name %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to 'Pick!', vote_up_game_path(game.id), :method => :post  %></td> 
  </tr> 
<% end %>
```

You would render the partial as follows

```
<%= render :partial => "game_partial", :locals => { :games => @games } %>
```

It is also important to ensure `@games` isn't nil.  If it is, you will still get your error - you should check your controller; typically I'd imagine your controller would have `@games  = Game.all`, of course this is dependent on your particular implementation.

Comment: With Rails 2, it isn't necessary to explicitly pass an instance variable generated from the controller to a partial.  The :locals parameter is only for creating a local variable within the context of the partial from a variable available from the caller.

Comment: That is indeed true, although passing the instance variables as locals tend to keep things a bit cleaner; I guess this open to personal preference.  I believe the docs elucidate this better, `You can also pass local variables into partials, making them even more powerful and flexible. For example, you can use this technique to reduce duplication between new and edit pages, while still keeping a bit of distinct content`